# Override "^c" or "ctrl-c" is the interrupt signal for shell interpreter

Tags: sigint, ctrl, stty

I would like to override ctrl-c as the signal interrupt character for all my shells and replace it with something else. I've looked at stty and xmodmap, but have not found anything that i understand as of yet.

If anyone has some ideas i would greatly appreciate it.